# Blackberry java radio streaming

Tags: blackberry, java-me, audio-streaming

I'm developing a radio app for BB 5.0 in java. I don't find a way to play the radio from the url stream address that I have. I use multiple formats but nothing works (.pls, .aac, .m3u). I get a `RuntimeException` every time I try to play the stream. The content is ok, I've checked it.

```
InputStream stream = Connector.openInputStream(urlPlay);
StreamConnection streamConnection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(urlPlay, Connector.READ);
InputStream  readAhead = streamConnection.openDataInputStream();
byte[] audioData = new byte[500];
readAhead.read(audioData,0,audioData.length);
ByteArrayInputStream in2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
player = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer(in2, "audio/aac");

System.out.println("REALIZE");
player.realize();                             
System.out.println("PREFETCH");
player.prefetch();
System.out.println("START");
player.start();
```

**Edit:**

When I use a URL from my .pls file I hear a little bit of my streaming but It stops immediately.

Comment: Where does the exception occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you are trying to play playlist files instead of an actual stream.  Generally, you need to parse those files yourself to get the real stream URLs.

If you open up that `.m3u` file, you will see that it is just a list of URLs.  Take one of those URLs and then try it.  Also, be sure you are setting the right content type.  You can determine what that type is with cURL or VLC.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But today I've parsed this file and I find that I need to buffer this data to play it on the manager, or it will crush. Any idea of how to do that?

Comment: @jmunoz, Sorry, I am not a Java coder.  I suggest opening up a separate question for that, since it is unrelated to your first question.

Comment: I've made another questions...see it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098239/blackberry-radio-app-straming-audio
Thanks