# Blackberry radio app streaming audio

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, audio-streaming, blackberry-5

I am building a radio app in BB 5. I have a .pls url where I find my urls to play the stream. My issue is. I need to build a Buffer to play this stream because the file which is downloaded is too big to play it inmediatly, but I don't know how to build this buffer. Any idea? 
I think that it must be something similar to that

[Streaming media BB](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Streaming-media-Start-to-finish/ta-p/488255)

But I want something more simple, only play and stop the radio streaming.

Comment: That link looks promising.  Did you try the suggestions in it?  Did you notice the [link to sample code](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/rim/attachments/rim/java_dev@tkb/398/2/StreamingPlayer.zip)?  I would recommend trying it out, and if it doesn't work for you, posting the streaming code you use, and ask for helping fixing it.

Comment: Yes Nate, I saw those things. But the problem here is the next. There is an object called CyclicBufferReader which doesn't exists in BB 5, and I can't run the project....tomorrow I will see if I can make it run.

Comment: There is no `CyclicBufferReader` used in that project.

Comment: Sorry, it's `CircularByteBuffer`

Comment: `CircularByteBuffer` doesn't exist in **any** BlackBerry OS version.  It's a separate class.  If you look closely at that document you link to, you'll see that they suggest you use an open source implementation of that class, that's found [at this address](http://ostermiller.org/utils/src/CircularByteBuffer.java.html).  The hyperlink is quite small, so it's easy to miss :)

Comment: I put the CircularByteBuffer from this link, but it doesn't work. ClassDefNotFoundError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've solved this, using the package of streaming from the code mentioned in the link above. I've added the `CircularByteBuffer` from the small link, showed in article. There is a class in the straming package which needs some fixes (in some `BufferOverflowException` and the resize method from `CircularByteBuffer`). And now my project is working! Great!

**ADD**

The fixes were in the `StreamingPlayer` class, there is a call to method resize with some int parameter. In the `CircularByteBuffer` code, the method is `resize()`, so doesn't need int parameters, it doubles the buffer capicity. So I change that call, using the resize() without int parameters.
The other fix is about `BufferOverflowException`. In the code this object has a `String`, but it gives an error. I delete this `Strings`.

Comment: If you can post the *fixes* you made to that class here, I'm sure some future readers would benefit from that.  Thanks!

Comment: there is a long delay before the streaming begins, does this problem happens with you? If not can you please post the fixes you made to the class?
Thanks;

Comment: Yeah I have the same issue, the streaming takes 20 secs to start